# Adding fees at each payment

Tags: commerce, rules

I am using [Commerce Fees](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_fees) module, as I want to add 5% as fees at the time of purchase.

I have added a fees type, and created a rule for this.

**My Problem** is that I whenever I go to checkout page where I have added some products such that my total order price is 1000, so I should be getting service tax of 50, but I am getting it to be 52.63 instead.

I am attaching my rules export, please help.

```
 { "rules_5_service_fees" : {
 "LABEL" : "5% Service Fees",
 "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
 "OWNER" : "rules",
 "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_fees" ],
 "ON" : { "commerce_fees_order" : [] },
 "DO" : [
   { "data_calc" : {
       "USING" : {
         "input_1" : [ "commerce-order:commerce-order-total:amount-decimal" ],
         "op" : "*",
         "input_2" : "5"
       },
       "PROVIDE" : { "result" : { "tax" : "Calculated Tax" } }
     }
   },
   { "commerce_fees_apply" : {
       "entity" : [ "commerce-order" ],
       "fee" : "service_fees",
       "amount" : [ "tax" ],
       "currency_code" : "USD",
       "include_tax" : "0"
     }
   }
 ]   
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as much of an answer as it is a recommendation. You should be doing this at the price calculation (per product) level, not order level. Not doing this can mean you're taking into account the taxes, shipping, other coupons/discounts, etc.

Comment: I think you are right, I will try doing it on product level